# How to delete vscode autocompletion that gives this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I enter 'data' in the Python code, this haunts after I push 'return' key. What should I do/disable?

[image: When I enter 'data' in the Python code, this haunts after I push 'return' key.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are code snippets. you change them by going to

> File > Preferences > user snippets

then, in the pop search box '*type python*' it will open a ***python.json*** file, where you'll find all the snippets for python and change or delete them as per your requirements. Basically, snippets are for speed up your development process. Another thing is if you don't want ***code intellisense*** then you can change the settings by going to,

> File > Preferences > Settings

this will open two tabs in the editor *1. default user settings 2. user settings* and in the user settings add this code,

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
},
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

which will turn off any auto suggestions when you enter a character. Although, you can get autocomplete suggestions by hitting *ctrl+space* in your code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To complet @Minhaz, you can also disable `acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter`, selections will only be accepted with TAB (but you can edit it with the Keyboard Shorcuts `acceptSelectedSuggestion`).

To do that, go into :

> File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shorcuts

find `acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter`, right-click on, then click `Remove Keybinding`.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, search `snippet`, choose `inline` for `Snippet  Suggestions` instead of `top`. This will prevent these snippets occupying top lines.

[image]